# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting Blender addons, tutorials, and other resources
- relevant events, conferences, or meetups
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2440).

Answer (score 13):

[image: Blend-Exchange!]

Comment: copy/paste from [2017](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2299/599)

Answer (score 9):

[image: All the blender news you can handle!]

Comment: copy/paste from [2017](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2298/599)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Animation Nodes]

Comment: Aside from being a promotion for Animation Nodes. I also wanted to inform the community about the "animation-nodes" tag as users seems to confuse it with the "animation" tag thinking it has something to do with the animation workflow of blender.

Comment: I like the idea of an ad to promote Animation nodes. The title font feels a bit boring to me, though. Also, could we get a picture that updates automatically, like the Blend Exchange ad?

Comment: @ScottMilner What font do you suggest we use? I am currently using Roboto Slab. I was not aware that the Blend Exchange ad can do that, I am not sure if we can do that, a requirement is that it "Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)" and it should be an image, so we can't really dynamically update the image without manually editing the post.

Comment: I think you should use the same font as you use below, only bold face. That way, it looks like a title, but is more coherent with the rest of the image. Alternatively, another sans-serif font would work. It's the difference in serifs vs no-serifs that's making it look off.

Comment: As far as the dynamic image goes, the Blend Exchange ad is hosted [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/dyimg/communityAdTwo.png), not on Imgur. There is some [PHP code](https://github.com/GiantCowFilms/Blend-Exchange/blob/master/Blend-exchangePHP/dynamicImg/communityAdTwo.php) that updates it automatically. I don't know what the best place to host this would be, though.

Comment: @ScottMilner Like this: [New Image](https://i.imgur.com/lCBQ7dX.png)? As for the dynamic image, my point is, the rules in the post states that images should be hosted on only imgur, so we can't use external domains, I am not sure if the Blend Exchange one will be a valid ad because of this.

Comment: That looks better, yeah. Since the new font is taller, I'd move it down a little bit. The Blend Exchange image has been hosted externally since 2015, and hasn't been a problem thus far.

Comment: SE has that only internal images rule, but they let that slide for any dynamically generated images. (there are lots of examples across the network.) Do note though you will need a host with https support.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms The font is a light and bold "Roboto Condensed". The design was created in Gravit Designer. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/100l15ktpU5N_wgBZoy_rG1Hm1QXmd3eI/view?usp=sharing) is the `SVG` and `gvdesign` files.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting