# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting Blender addons, tutorials, and other resources
- relevant events, conferences, or meetups
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2580).

Comment: Does the file size limit double when we make a high DPI image? If not can you use a jpg? (I can not get a good looking png at 150kb)

Answer (score 20):

[image: Blender Development Fund - support core developers to work on maintaining and improving Blender]

Comment: (Submitted on behalf of the Blender Foundation)

Answer (score 14):

[image: Blend-Exchange!]

Comment: copy/paste from [2018](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2442/26640)

Comment: @GiantCowFilms none of the images on your website seem to render.

Comment: @asoftbird I recently upgraded the server to an entirely re-written version of Blend-Exchange. That is probably the cause of the problem. That being said, it seems to me like the image serving is working. Are you still having issues, and if so, can you provide some information about what the response is when you request the image from the servers?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2QmD.png This is what I'm seeing; in the source code of your edit you don't actually seem to use the image anywhere as it's commented out.  See this for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o63l2.png

It's not visible on both the current PC and on the one I use at work. 
I hope that's enough information.

Comment: @asoftbird I did a bunch of checks, and cleared the [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) cache. Everything seems to be normal, and the images are being served correctly by the server. Is it possible you have an add blocker or firewall that blocks cloudflare's CDN?

Comment: The topic's about _advertising_ images, though I hadn't considered it might have been the ad blocker just doing it's job. Guess that works well, at least. I'm a dumbass, sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: @asoftbird I just checked with uBlock Origin on and off. It''s the adblocker at work which seems to be picking up "ads" in the URL. This answer,  and Omar's answer are blank, while rest have images with Adblock on.

Comment: @asoftbird ankii Thanks for reporting and debugging this issue. I have updated the URLs to ones that won't be blocked by ad blockers.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Animation Nodes]

Comment: From [2018](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/community-promotion-ads-2018/2442#2442).

Answer (score 6):

[image: Spring - The next open movie from Blender coming soon]

Comment: Just saw this as an ad and noticed it is outdated. Can this be edited to say "Spring, latest open movie?" - since this makes it look like it still hasn't been released.   (I un-upvoted it so the outdated version wouldn't be shown as an ad, but would obviously re-upvote it later)

Comment: @X-27 thanks for noticing. (I forgot about it). You already fixed it (ad is not being shown) and I do not think we still need an ad for spring running.

Answer (score 5):

[image: All the blender news you can handle!]

Comment: copy/paste from [2018](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2443/26640)

Answer (score -2):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting